# Google Sheet Script not triggered when sheet is edited by service account?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I have written a gs function that sends an email when someone inserts a new row in the sheet. It works fine when users manually insert data, however that sheet is also used by a service account which inserts a new row through the API, and the edit event is not triggered in that case.

This is the trigger that I'm using

[image]

I created the script and the trigger as the owner of the sheet, but that didn't fix anything, so I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to trigger a user event with code is to use the Sheets API, with a special setting to set the value as `USER_ENTERED`  And it only works with the "On Change" event.  So, you'll need to create a second trigger for "On Change" but you can use the same function name.  Although you may need to modify the function to deal with a different event object.  Or you could use a different function.

So, your service account will need to run code that uses the Sheets API to set values in your Google Sheet.

You can use either the REST API or the Sheets Advanced Service.

To use the Advance Sheets Service the code would look like the following:

```
function writeToSheet() {
  id = "Put the Sheet ID here";

  var rowValues = [
    ["one","two"],
  ];

  var request = {
    'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED',
    'data': [
      {
        "range": "Sheet1!A2:B2",
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": rowValues,
      },
    ],
  };

  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(request, id);
  Logger.log('response ' + JSON.stringify(response))
}
```

For the REST API the basic code is as follows:

```
function writeToSheet() {
  var id,options,range,response,sh,ss,url,values;

  id = 'Put the spreadsheet ID here';
  range = "Sheet1!A1:A1";
  values = {values: [['3','two','nine']]}; // Modified

  url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" +
    id + "/values/" + range + ":append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";

  options = {
    "method":"post",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    "contentType": "application/json", // Added
    "payload": JSON.stringify(values) // Added
  }

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
  response = JSON.parse(response);

  //Logger.log('response ' + JSON.stringify(response))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that for your purpose, you can quite replace the trigger on an event with a time-driven trigger (ie, check if new rows have been added every minute and if so, send an email). This is easier (imho) than making a request to Google advance serivce and will not require new permissions.

To do this, you will need to add a column with the status or write somewhere the data on the lines already sent.

The code might look something like this:

```
function checkNewRows() {

// Get sheet
const ss = gSpreadsheet;
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MySheet'); // Change sheet name

const statusColumnIndex = 10;
const nameColumnIndex = 1;

// Get data from sheet
let sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

// Iterate through the sheet
for (let rowIndex in sheetData) {

  // Skip headers
  if (rowIndex == 0) continue;

  let rowNum = parseInt(rowIndex) + 1;

  // Get current item
  let thisItem = sheetData[rowIndex];

  // Get name or some other column to check if it is non empty
  let name = thisItem[nameColumnIndex];

  // Check if we need to process this row (it is non empty)
  if (name == undefined || name.length == 0) continue;

  // Get status
  let status = thisItem[statusColumnIndex].toLowerCase().trim();

  // Check if this row already been processed before
  if (status == 'sended') continue;

  // Email new data
  sendEmail(thisItem);

  // Change status
  sheet.getRange(rowNum, statusColumnIndex).setValue('Sended');
}
}
```

However, a similar task works for me in my Apps Script: the trigger fires every time Zapier adds a new row.

1. I'm using installable trigger (like you apparently https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
2. In the onEdit function, I track if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW') to run my function.
3. So, double check if you have nothing on your executions logs. Maybe there are some errors.